# Multi-label Token Classification Using Contextual Embeddings For Each Word

Tags: python, bert-language-model, word-embedding, multilabel-classification

I am trying to design a model for an argument mining task on a token-level basis. I have extracted contextual bert embeddings for each token and stored the embeddings in a dataframe which looks like this:

[image: Dataframe for each token, its bert embedding vector, and 32 labels]

What is the best model for this multi-label classification task? Can I pass the bert embeddings as the embedding layer of a classifier as they are stored in this dataframe? The embeddings are calculated per word, so sub-tokens have also been included and the average embeddings are saved. I am trying to classify each token for 32 labels that show whether it is an argumentative component, and if so, what position it takes and how far it is from its related component. Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you still need, that's a way to do multi-label token classification (in short, manually change the loss function of the Trainer form CrossEntropyLoss to BCEWithLogitsLoss).
I haven't tried it yet so can't help so much. Hope it helps you or other users searching for this topic.
https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/multi-label-token-classification/16509/1